# Show $S_2 \cong Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do I show  $S_2 \cong Z_2$? I'd say it makes good sense when thinking about both groups are of order two, and they both are abelian, but I'm not sure how to tackle the problem.

Comment: How many groups of order 2 do you know, abelian or not?

Comment: Can you construct an explicit homomorphism?

Comment: I would suggest writing down the group table of *any* group of order $2$. It's a $2\times 2$ table so there are only $4$ entries to write down. My hint would be to use the existence of an identity (how many elements of the table does that determine?) and something else (of your choice) to determine the table, thus determining the group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** You need to exhibit an isomorphism between the two groups, which is a homomorphism that is also a bijection. There are only two bijections $S_2\to Z_2$, and you can check the definition to see that one of them is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\mathbb{Z}_{2}=\left\lbrace [0], [1]\right\rbrace$, and that $S_{2}=\left\lbrace (1), (1 \:2)\right\rbrace$. Also recall that $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is a group with respect to the operation $\oplus$ and that $S_{2}$ is a group with respect to composition ($\circ$). Let $\xi:\mathbb{Z}_{2} \to S_{2}$ be defined in the following manner.

$\xi([0])=(1)$ and $\xi([1])=(1\:2)$

Then $\xi$ preserves group structure, and the following is apparent.

$\xi([0]\oplus [1])=\xi([0+1])=\xi([1])$

$=(1\:2)$

$=(1\:2) \circ (1)$

$=(1)\circ (1\:2)$

$=\xi([0]) \circ \xi([1])$

Therefore, $\xi$ is a homomorphism. And since the mapping is also one-to-one and onto, it is an isomorphism. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \approx S_{2}$.